# Alert doesn't trigger within on change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My alert doesn't trigger here.

```
$('.filters-select').on('change', function() {
var $this = $(this);
var $buttonGroup = $this('.filters-select');
alert('test');
var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
filters[filterGroup] = $this.attr('data-filter');
var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
$container.isotope({filter:filterValue});
});
```

Though it does work when it's placed as the first thing in the function.

```
$('.filters-select').on('change', function() {
alert('test');
var $this = $(this);
var $buttonGroup = $this('.filters-select');
var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
filters[filterGroup] = $this.attr('data-filter');
var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
$container.isotope({filter:filterValue});
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<select class="filters-select" data-filter-group="market">
  <option value="*">Select a Market Category</option>
  <option value=".industrial" data-filter=".industrial">Industrial</option>
  <option value=".commercial" data-filter=".commercial">Commercial</option>
  <option value=".government" data-filter=".government">Government</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please put all this code inside JSfiddle.

Comment: Are you by chance receiving any errors in the dev console? `$this('.filters-select');` this code just doesn't look right.

Comment: `var $this = $(this); var $buttonGroup = $this('.filters-select');`  <-- makes no sense, did you mean to use `find`?

Comment: Yes, $this('.filters-select') doesn't make sense. What are your trying to accomplish on change?

Comment: The alert doesn't work because the rest of your JS isn't valid and causes an error before the alert fires. Take a look in the dev console.

Comment: Please get in the habit of checking your code for obvious errors before posting it. If you're not developing your site with your browser's developer tools open and error reporting turned on, you *need* to be.

Comment: placing alerts at different points within your JS code is a way to debug it. If the alter fires as the first statement, your method gets called. Move it down after the first code statement, if it fires, that line is good... continue with this process and the first time it doesn't fire means the line above it is where the code is broken/has an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code: `$this('.filters-select');` is not valid, so the browser isn't going to alert anything that comes after it. It thinks that `$this` is trying to be a method, which it obviously isn't.

In your `change` event, `$(this)` is going to return the `select`, not the selected `option`.

I'm pretty sure this is what you want.

```
$('.filters-select').on('change', function() {
  alert('test');
  var filterGroup = $(this).attr('data-filter-group');
  filters[filterGroup] = $(this).find(":selected").attr('data-filter');
  var filterValue = concatValues(filters);
  $container.isotope({
    filter: filterValue
  });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped! Consider marking this as correct to help other user's find it in future!

Answer (score 1):

The reason your first block of code doesn't fire is because this line is not valid JS:

```
var $buttonGroup = $this('.filters-select');
```

The second block is breaking too on this line, it just so happens you moved the `alert` above it.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with `$this('.filters-select');`, but I'd consider removing it and rethinking your strategy with it. For future reference, the developers console in your browser can be your best friend when developing.

Comment: I'm trying to do some filtering with isotope as seen here http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JEojz

But instead use select drop downs to filter the content as i'm trying here: http://codepen.io/dru_nasty/pen/QyEVoz/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery you need to call **$(document).ready()** to start the code within.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.filters-select').change(function() {
        alert('Teste');
    });
});
```